# Multiple (more than 50) select2 in 1 screen with the same dropdown values causes page to load slowly

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a screen that you can add a new row in a dynamic table. This row has a select2 element, sometimes the dynamic table will add upto 50 or more rows. This select2 has upto 1000 options. This causes the page to load slowly. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use `async and await` in every function.
It may help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).